# Remove extra brackets in a JSON Array for compatibility in DataTable

Tags: c#, php, arrays

I return JSON to my RestAPI connection and Deserialize it to DataTable.
This work if I am using only one Array, but I have a Array in Array because there are two different types of Database tables and I need to see both of them in one DataTable.

My DataTable can't work with the extra brackets there you can see around my first item in my JSON below.

I need a method to remove them or another Solution to come my goal a little bit near.

Here I want to get data from two different tables, I don't want to mix them like inner join does, that's the reason why I tried to solve this with a foreach and store it in a Array.

Actually it does what I want but the extra brackets make troubles.

How can I remove them or is there a other Solution?

**PHP**

```
$arr = array(
    "Massnahmenliste",
    "Terminliste"
);
$data = array();
foreach($arr as $table)
{ 
    $data[] = \DB::table($table)
    ->join('Firma', $table.'.id_Firma', '=', 'Firma.id_Firma') 
    ->select($table.'.*', 'Firma.*')
    ->orderBy('Termin')
    ->get();
}
return $data;
```

**C#**

```
var options = new RestClientOptions(GetUrl)
{
    ThrowOnAnyError = true
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
RestResponse response = client.Get(request);

using (DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content, (typeof(DataTable))))();
```

**JSON:**

```
[
   [
      [
         {
            "id_Massnahmenliste":2,
            "id_Firma":1,
            "Termin":"2022-01-01 10:10:10",
            "Beschreibung":"Beschreibungs Test",
            "MassnahmenNr":100,
            "Abgeschlossen":0,
            "id_Terminliste":0,
            "ServiceNr":0,
            "Servicestand":"0",
            "Firma":"Coding GmbH",
            "Strasse":"Spitalstr",
            "Hausnummer":"4",
            "Postleitzahl":77652,
            "Ort":"Offenburg",
            "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-12",
            "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
         }
      ],
      [
         {
            "id_Terminliste":1,
            "id_Firma":1,
            "Termin":"2022-08-31 00:00:00",
            "Beschreibung":"Servicetermin",
            "ServiceNr":1,
            "Servicestand":"1 von 4",
            "Abgeschlossen":1,
            "id_Massnahmenliste":0,
            "MassnahmenNr":0,
            "Firma":"Coding GmbH",
            "Strasse":"Spitalstr",
            "Hausnummer":"4",
            "Postleitzahl":77652,
            "Ort":"Offenburg",
            "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-12",
            "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
         },
         {
            "id_Terminliste":5,
            "id_Firma":2,
            "Termin":"2022-08-31 00:00:00",
            "Beschreibung":"Servicetermin",
            "ServiceNr":1,
            "Servicestand":"1 von 4",
            "Abgeschlossen":0,
            "id_Massnahmenliste":0,
            "MassnahmenNr":0,
            "Firma":"Coding GmbH",
            "Strasse":"Spitalstr",
            "Hausnummer":"4",
            "Postleitzahl":77652,
            "Ort":"Offenburg",
            "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-12",
            "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
         },
         {
            "id_Terminliste":9,
            "id_Firma":3,
            "Termin":"2022-08-31 00:00:00",
            "Beschreibung":"Servicetermin",
            "ServiceNr":1,
            "Servicestand":"1 von 4",
            "Abgeschlossen":0,
            "id_Massnahmenliste":0,
            "MassnahmenNr":0,
            "Firma":"Coding GmbH",
            "Strasse":"Spitalstr",
            "Hausnummer":"4",
            "Postleitzahl":77652,
            "Ort":"Offenburg",
            "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-12",
            "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
         },
         {
            "id_Terminliste":2,
            "id_Firma":1,
            "Termin":"2022-11-30 00:00:00",
            "Beschreibung":"Servicetermin",
            "ServiceNr":2,
            "Servicestand":"2 von 4",
            "Abgeschlossen":0,
            "id_Massnahmenliste":0,
            "MassnahmenNr":0,
            "Firma":"Coding GmbH",
            "Strasse":"Spitalstr",
            "Hausnummer":"4",
            "Postleitzahl":77652,
            "Ort":"Offenburg",
            "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-12",
            "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
         },
         {
            "id_Terminliste":6,
            "id_Firma":2,
            "Termin":"2022-11-30 00:00:00",
            "Beschreibung":"Servicetermin",
            "ServiceNr":2,
            "Servicestand":"2 von 4",
            "Abgeschlossen":0,
            "id_Massnahmenliste":0,
            "MassnahmenNr":0,
            "Firma":"Coding GmbH",
            "Strasse":"Spitalstr",
            "Hausnummer":"4",
            "Postleitzahl":77652,
            "Ort":"Offenburg",
            "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-12",
            "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
         },
         {
            "id_Terminliste":10,
            "id_Firma":3,
            "Termin":"2022-11-30 00:00:00",
            "Beschreibung":"Servicetermin",
            "ServiceNr":2,
            "Servicestand":"2 von 4",
            "Abgeschlossen":0,
            "id_Massnahmenliste":0,
            "MassnahmenNr":0,
            "Firma":"Coding GmbH",
            "Strasse":"Spitalstr",
            "Hausnummer":"4",
            "Postleitzahl":77652,
            "Ort":"Offenburg",
            "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-12",
            "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
         },
         {
            "id_Terminliste":3,
            "id_Firma":1,
            "Termin":"2023-02-28 00:00:00",
            "Beschreibung":"Servicetermin",
            "ServiceNr":3,
            "Servicestand":"3 von 4",
            "Abgeschlossen":0,
            "id_Massnahmenliste":0,
            "MassnahmenNr":0,
            "Firma":"Coding GmbH",
            "Strasse":"Spitalstr",
            "Hausnummer":"4",
            "Postleitzahl":77652,
            "Ort":"Offenburg",
            "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-12",
            "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
         },
         {
            "id_Terminliste":7,
            "id_Firma":2,
            "Termin":"2023-02-28 00:00:00",
            "Beschreibung":"Servicetermin",
            "ServiceNr":3,
            "Servicestand":"3 von 4",
            "Abgeschlossen":0,
            "id_Massnahmenliste":0,
            "MassnahmenNr":0,
            "Firma":"Coding GmbH",
            "Strasse":"Spitalstr",
            "Hausnummer":"4",
            "Postleitzahl":77652,
            "Ort":"Offenburg",
            "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-12",
            "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
         }
      ]
   ]
]
```

Comment: I think you have to merge two arrays, and also two array object keys are not the same, you can handle that but first you have to get all objects in single array.

Comment: yeah but i thought thats what i already did? In my PHP script i have a foreach that add the information to the array. So this should be one Array or am i wrong?

Comment: What is the exact desired json output? Have you tried a variadic `array_push()`? `array_push($data, ...$resultSet);` Are you simply asking how to flatten the array?  What framework are you using? There is no framework tag on your question.

Comment: i use Lavarel, and Lavarel is poorly not accepting this :/ but i answered here to my own question, i found a solution for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution, I'm sure it's not very clean, but it does what I need and it works.

*Remember that these are two different tables and are not related to each other.*

First, I can't use array_push since I'm using Lavarel.
So this is how I solved my problem with additional brackets around the first of two tables in a Array...

First I get all my information and put it in an array, then I replace some characters in a foreach and append it to a string. After that, I subtract characters from the whole string that were previously automatically placed by the conversion.

The last part just gives me the option to check if any of the tables is null then it replies "[ ,'" which I also replace with just "[".

```
$data = array();
            
           
$data[] = \DB::table('Massnahmenliste')
->join('Firma', 'Massnahmenliste.id_Firma', '=', 'Firma.id_Firma') 
->select('Massnahmenliste.*', 'Firma.*')
->orderBy('Termin')
->get();
$data[] = \DB::table('Terminliste')
->join('Firma', 'Terminliste.id_Firma', '=', 'Firma.id_Firma') 
->select('Terminliste.*', 'Firma.*')
->orderBy('Termin')
->get();


$string = "";


foreach(array_chunk($data, 2) as $value) {
    
    $string .= "{{$value[0]} {$value[1]}}";
    $string = str_replace("]", "",   $string);
    $string = str_replace("[", ",",   $string);
  
}

$string = str_replace("}{", "},{",   $string);
$string = substr($string, 2, strlen($string) - 3);
$string = $string[1]."[".substr($string,0);
$string = substr($string, 1, strlen($string) - 2);
$string .="}]";

if (strpos($string, '[ ,') === 0) 
{
    $string = str_replace("[ ,", "[",   $string);
}

return  $string;
```

**BEFORE**

```
[
[
    {
        "id_Massnahmenliste":3,
        "id_Firma":4,
        "Termin":"2022-09-11 00:00:00",
        "Beschreibung":"Nachkontrolle",
        "MassnahmenNr":0,
        "Abgeschlossen":0,
        "id_Terminliste":0,
        "ServiceNr":0,
        "Servicestand":null,
        "Firma":"Developer Akademie",
        "Strasse":"Street",
        "Hausnummer":"4",
        "Postleitzahl":1234,
        "Ort":"Ort",
        "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-14",
        "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
    }
],
[
    {
        "id_Terminliste":13,
        "id_Firma":4,
        "Termin":"2022-08-31 00:00:00",
        "Beschreibung":"Servicetermin",
        "ServiceNr":1,
        "Servicestand":"1 von 12",
        "Abgeschlossen":1,
        "id_Massnahmenliste":0,
        "MassnahmenNr":0,
        "Firma":"Developer Akademie",
        "Strasse":"Street",
        "Hausnummer":"4",
        "Postleitzahl":1234,
        "Ort":"Ort",
        "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-14",
        "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
    },
    {
        "id_Terminliste":14,
        "id_Firma":4,
        "Termin":"2022-09-30 00:00:00",
        "Beschreibung":"Servicetermin",
        "ServiceNr":2,
        "Servicestand":"2 von 12",
        "Abgeschlossen":0,
        "id_Massnahmenliste":0,
        "MassnahmenNr":0,
        "Firma":"Developer Akademie",
        "Strasse":"Street",
        "Hausnummer":"4",
        "Postleitzahl":1234,
        "Ort":"Ort",
        "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-14",
        "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
    }
]
```

]

**AFTER**

```
[
    {
        "id_Massnahmenliste":3,
        "id_Firma":4,
        "Termin":"2022-09-11 00:00:00",
        "Beschreibung":"Nachkontrolle",
        "MassnahmenNr":0,
        "Abgeschlossen":0,
        "id_Terminliste":0,
        "ServiceNr":0,
        "Servicestand":null,
        "Firma":"Developer Akademie",
        "Strasse":"Street",
        "Hausnummer":"4",
        "Postleitzahl":12345,
        "Ort":"Ort",
        "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-14",
        "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
    },
    {
        "id_Terminliste":13,
        "id_Firma":4,
        "Termin":"2022-08-31 00:00:00",
        "Beschreibung":"Servicetermin",
        "ServiceNr":1,
        "Servicestand":"1 von 12",
        "Abgeschlossen":1,
        "id_Massnahmenliste":0,
        "MassnahmenNr":0,
        "Firma":"Developer Akademie",
        "Strasse":"Street",
        "Hausnummer":"4",
        "Postleitzahl":12345,
        "Ort":"Ort",
        "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-14",
        "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
    },
    {
        "id_Terminliste":14,
        "id_Firma":4,
        "Termin":"2022-09-30 00:00:00",
        "Beschreibung":"Servicetermin",
        "ServiceNr":2,
        "Servicestand":"2 von 12",
        "Abgeschlossen":0,
        "id_Massnahmenliste":0,
        "MassnahmenNr":0,
        "Firma":"Developer Akademie",
        "Strasse":"Street",
        "Hausnummer":"4",
        "Postleitzahl":12345,
        "Ort":"Ort",
        "Vertragsbeginn":"2022-08-14",
        "Vertragsende":"2025-08-31"
    }
]
```